# PhpStorm не выводит результаты в браузер

Tags: phpstorm, php, ide

Я использую phpStorm 7.1.3 и PHP 5.4.19. Когда я использую функции из библиотек, например gd2, у меня есть intellisense (подсказки среды) и код успешно компилируется. Но когда я хочу вывести результаты в браузер, то у меня появляется вкладка с индикатором загрузки и ничего не происходит. В php.ini стандартные библиотеки я указываю.

Как мне настроить phpStorm или PHP, что бы я мог смотреть результаты в браузере?

Comment: А как вы код компилируете?

Comment: Нажимаю Shift+F10. Я после установки в настройках выбрал папку, где у меня установлен PHP и все. При обычных операциях, типа арифметика, echo, без библиотек у меня работает на ура.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы Web-приложения в бразузере необходим Web-сервер. На windows успешно применяются так-называемые Apache+MySQL+PHP бандлы. От себя рекомендую Wamp. Гуглите wamp устанавливаете, запоминаете папку, куда установили, в браузере вводим localhost -- должна вывестись информация от WAMP. Как только это вышло. Копируете ваши php файлы в папку где установлен wamp (обычно C:\wamp\www) в подпапку www. Например в www скопировали файл test.php теперь его можно запустить в браузере как http://localhost/test.php

Удачи!

Comment: Огромное спасибо, Антон. Но дело в том, что если я не пользуюсь библиотеками, то в браузер все выводится. Например, я могу обработать регулярным выражением строку. И результат я смогу вывести в браузер. Я это к чему, на таких же задачах сервер работает, значит как то и с библиотеками можно настроить. Но за совет спасибо, обязательно попробую.

Comment: @iplot, а PHP который с сервером идёт и тот, к которому вы обращаетесь из phpStorm - один и тот же?  
Если нет, то, быть может, они настроены по-разному?